# Table border css behaving differently between browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table with a missing column, to give the illusion of two tables side-by-side. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4ygah2o/1/) (reproduced below) shows my current code.

The fiddle gives the required output in Chrome 58.0.3029.110 and Opera 45.0:

[image]

However, the output with Firefox 53.0.3 and IE11 is:

[image]

Any idea how I can persuade all 4 browsers to show the top image?

I've tried variations on

```
table.table1 tr.totals td.hidden {
  border-top : none;
}
```

but with no success. On Firefox, turning off `collapse` fixes the borders, but all the cells move apart.

Here's the code, since SO wants it:

```
<table class='table1'>
<tbody>
<tr>               <td>1</td><td>2</td><td class='hidden'></td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr class='totals'><td>4</td><td>5</td><td class='hidden'></td><td>6</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

.table1 {
    border-collapse : collapse;
}
table.table1 td {
  background-color : #e5e5e5;
  padding : 3px 6px 6px 3px;
  border : 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}
table.table1 .hidden {
  visibility : hidden;
}
table.table1 .totals {
  border-top : 3px double #7f7f7f;
}
```

Comment: `display:none` makes the entire column disappear, unfortunately...

Comment: Read my answer, it should work (works for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest adding the double border to the top of each cell in the `.totals` row (instead of across the whole row), then setting the `border: none` attribute in the `.hidden` cells.

```css
.table1 {
    border-collapse : collapse;
}
table.table1 td {
  background-color : #e5e5e5;
  padding : 3px 6px 6px 3px;
  border : 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}
table.table1 .totals td {
  border-top : 3px double #7f7f7f;
}
table.table1 .hidden {
  visibility : hidden;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table class='table1'>
<tbody>
<tr>               <td>1</td><td>2</td><td class='hidden'></td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr class='totals'><td>4</td><td>5</td><td class='hidden'></td><td>6</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's done it - thanks. Didn't need the `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Setting `visibility:hidden` is not enough. You should add `border: none` with `!important` to override the table's `border` definitions:

```
table.table1.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This gets rid of the top and bottom borders, but not the double border in the middle